# Nagios sending mails on both IDs

Tags: nagios

not able to define separate contacts for different environments. alert notification is sent on both mail id rather it should be send to only one that i have specified in service and host as well.by 
Please help me out.

Comment: post your service group configurations

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the Configuration, it is hard to guess, but i think you are using some wrong configuration.

It should look like this :

Your hostconfiguration:

```
define host{
        use                     **host-template**
        host_name               **hostname**
        hostgroups              **if you have any**
        address                 **the IP**
        contacts                **Admin for Host**
}
```

Your serviceconfiguration (e.g. CPU)

```
define service{
        use                     service-template-interval-60min
        service_description     CPU
        host_name               **hostname**
    check_command           check_nrpe_var!check_var_load!15,10,5!30,25,20
        contacts                **Your Admin Contact for Service**
}
```